# Is there any way to use the salary calculator for previous years?

Tags: support, salary-calculator

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary

I was wondering if there is any way to get the developer survey results for a previous year but still be able to submit the same inputs to calculate the result as that webpage above.

Effectively I want to compare how salary has changed with only the year being the variable. (So same position type, tech stack, years of experience).

Comment: Not editing this (at least yet), but if it turns out this isn't possible, it should be retagged as [feature-request].